# Stackoverflow Error in Staircase Problem when step size is greater than 3

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to solve the staircase problem in java with a method that gets the number of stairs (n) and the maximum step size (maxStep). Somehow it works until step size is > 3 after that I get a Stackoverflow error but I don't know why that is.

```
    public static int climbStairs(int n, int maxStep) {

    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n == 2) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxStep; i++) {
            count += climbStairs(n - i, maxStep);
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the staircase problem is? Also, sharing some sample input and the output expected for it

Comment: I got the error, it can be reproduced. Try inputs 30,10 for example

Comment: You haven't accounted for `n<0`, which will happen if `maxStep` is larger than `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code hope it will work.

```
public static int climbStairs2(int n, int maxStep) {

        if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else if (n < maxStep) {
            return n;
        } else {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= maxStep; i++) {
                count += climbStairs2(n - i, maxStep);
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't check whether the maxstep is smaller than the step count. This means that after a while, the i<=maxstep can be > n, which results in negative n for the next recursion. If it once turns to the negatives, it will recurse infinitely. To fix it, just check for n<=maxstep or n<=0.

Example of your 'bad' code: Try inputs 5,4: it will start the method with n=

- 5
- 4
- 3
- -1
- -2

Comment: thank you for the explanation, you are right that makes sense